# Using mockjax with mocha

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, mockjax

I am experimenting with building a very simple API using express and would like to use Mocha for testing. I also want to use jquery-mockjax to mock third-party API calls but not sure how to go about that. I used `npm install` to install Mocha globally, and jquery and jquery-mockjax within the app.

How do I go about requiring mockjax and the xmldom library (to mock xml response returned by third-party API)? Code wise, here's how I imagined it would look like but doesn't work:

```
var request = require('supertest');
var should = require('should');
var $ = require('jquery');
var constants = require('../lib/constants');

require('jquery-mockjax');
// require('/opt/orbit/orbit-api/node_modules/jquery-mockjax/lib/jquery.xmldom.js');

var server = request.agent("https://localhost:8080/api");

describe("As a user, I", function() {

  beforeEach(function() {
    this.timeout(0); //disables mocha 2 second timeout limit
  });

  it("should be able to sign in", function(done) {
    $.mockjax({
      url: apiUrl + 'auth/signin',
      type: 'post',
      responseXML: '<tsResponse><credentials token="1234" ><site id="1" contentUrl="url" /><user id="1" /></credentials></tsResponse>'
    });

    server
      .post("/auth/signin")
      .send({
        username: username,
        password: password
      })
      .expect("Content-type", /json/)
      .end(function(err, res) {
        res.body.http_code.should.equal(200);
    done();
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery in your Node project? Mockjax is intended to mock out Ajax calls made using jQuery in an application while testing that application. Not many people use jQuery to run Ajax in a Node app...